org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService supported in wildfly 27?
I want to upgrade my app to wildfly 27.
In the web.xml file we use
servlet name is SOAPMonitorService
servlet class is  org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService
When i run the server i get an error that SOAPMonitorService doesn't implement Jakarta.
Is there an equivale class in jakarta? How can i implement it to work in wildfly 27?
Thanks in advance!

Why exactly are you using Axis-specific classes instead of standard JAX-WS API? You appear to be targeting a full fledged JEE server already (WildFly), and not a barebones servletcontainer such as Tomcat wherein you'd normally have to manually install all the lacking JEE APIs not provided by the target runtime.
